# how to properly link mingw libraries using cmake and vcpkg?

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I've getting used to simple cmake codes like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(trial VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(trial main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(trial PRIVATE fmt::fmt)
```

however, it doesn't work on Mingw, the errors are something like this

```
[build] C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\trial.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `void fmt::v8::print<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&>(fmt::v8::basic_format_string<char, fmt::v8::type_identity<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&>::type>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)':
[build] C:/PROGRA~1/Vcpkg/INSTAL~1/X64-WI~1/include/fmt/core.h:3208: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN3fmt2v86vprintENS0_17basic_string_viewIcEENS0_17basic_format_argsINS0_20basic_format_contextINS0_8appenderEcEEEE'
```

soI have to specify the `.a` and `.dll.a` lib.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(trial VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories("C:/Program Files/Vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-static/include")

add_executable(trial main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(trial "C:/Program Files/Vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-static/lib/libfmt.a")
# target_link_libraries(trial PRIVATE fmt::fmt)
# target_link_libraries(trial fmt::fmt-header-only)
```

This is kind of strange, what should I do to properly link mingw libraries using cmake and vcpkg?

[Makefile and Makefile2](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZxZPm2fhxT/)

Comment: What does it do? Did you look at the generated makefile? I use fmt from vcpkg but I am using msvc. Also did you specify the toolchain file?

Comment: I can hardly understand the Makefile, but I 've updated it with Makefile and Makefile2.  it works fine on both x64-windows and x64-linux except x64-mingw. toolchain is specified with `"-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\\Program Files\\Vcpkg\\scripts\\buildsystems\\vcpkg.cmake"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am rather late, but here it in case it helps:

Specifying library locations by hand shouldn't be required, the problem is somewhere else.

This error is at build time so it seems that it is passed cmake configuration without errors. Can you post the cmake conf log? perhaps if you tried specifying both `--triplet=` and `--host-triplet=` ?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, It reminds me of the `triplet` problem. It turns out that cmake is trying to use fmt in `x64-window`. The problem is solved after setting `-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-mingw-static`. It's a pity cmake can't deduce triplet from toolkit

Comment: I do not think any of these is cmake's issue. apparently vcpkg by default prefers `x64-windows` which is "officially supported" whereas the `x??-mingw-*` ones are "community based".

Answer (score 0):

lets use link_directories:https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html

```
include_directories("C:/Program Files/Vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-static/include")
add_executable(trial main.cpp)
target_link_directories(trial PUBLIC "C:/Program Files/Vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-static/lib/")
target_link_libraries(trial PRIVATE fmt)
```

Comment: kind of weird still, I just want to find_package() once for all, is it feasible?

Comment: What does `One for all` mean ?

Comment: means I can simply `find_package()` and `target_link_libraries(target fmt::fmt)` ,  no need to take platform and different lib files into account

Comment: I don't know what command can do that . The answer only show you how to link a lib without specify path of each one.

Comment: He is right. He should be able to just use `find_package()` and `target_link_libraries(target fmt::fmt)`. There should be no need to meddle with the link directories. This should be reported upstream to vcpkg or fmt itslef.

Comment: Its probably some bug in the vcpkg building for the `x64-mingw-static` triplet